# Laravel collection pluck method not working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, faker, laravel-collection

I've entered the fantastic world of Laravel and I am currently looking into seeding a database with fake data for testing.

I have a couple of tables I want to work with; **projects** and **stories**.

The stories table has the columns; **id**, **name** and **project_id** (which is a fk to the projects table).

My projects table is already populated with a list of 10 projects. Now I need to populate 100 stories with random projects associated. I have the approach below.

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('stories')->delete();
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE stories AUTO_INCREMENT = 1');

    $faker = Faker::create();

    foreach(range(1, 100) as $index)
    {
        Story::create([
            'reference' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 9999),
            'name' => $faker->sentence(6),
            'project_id' => Project::orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->get()->first()->pluck('id')
        ]);
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way of doing what I need. However, when performing this code every story's project_id is set to 1; the first project's id.

When I perform the following command in tinker... It always returns 1 as the id.

```
Project::orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->get()->first()->pluck('id')
```

But when I perform the next command in tinker...

```
Project::orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->get()->first()
```

It returns a random project every time. Which is strange. Because if everything up to ->pluck() is working then pluck() should fetch that collected items id... Right? This is what the above command returns.

```
<App\Project #000000000c385908000000000de30942> {
   id: 6,
   name: "New Bernadetteton",
   cover_photo_url: "/uploads/covers/horizon-grass.png",
   created_at: "2015-07-08 16:32:15",
   updated_at: "2015-07-08 16:32:15" }
```

See below screenshot for my terminal window to illustrate what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

1. With `->first()` you get the actual project model
2. Then you call `pluck('id')` on it. BUT the `Model` class doesn't have that method.
3. So with, as with every method the `Model` doesn't know, it redirects the call to a new query builder instance of the model.
4. In the end, that call ends up here:

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder@value`

```
public function value($column)
{
    $result = $this->first(array($column));

    if ($result) return $result->{$column};
}
```

As you can see, that method runs a new query, using `first()` and then returns the desired row.

---

Now what you actually want is either:

#### 1. Don't use `pluck` at all

There isn't really a need to use that method, you can just access the model property:

```
'project_id' => Project::orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->first()->id
```

#### 2. Use `pluck`, but do it right

```
'project_id' => Project::orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->pluck('id')
```

---

And btw, the main method is called `value()`. `pluck()` is just an alias. I recommend using `value()` in new code. It's possible that the alias will be removed some day. (Obviously just in a new release and with a note in the upgrade guide, so don't panic ;))

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I now call ->id on the ->first() method directly. I had no idea it referenced the model and just thought it wiped the result set down to 1 (the first object).